# First time starting an API, spark-java and elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spark-java

I've been given a challenge to build a RESTful API in Java, using Spark and elasticsearch. I've never made an API, or using frameworks before so I'm having trouble even getting to the coding. I'll try to ask this as best as I can, but I not sure what to ask honestly. What I "think" I want to know is how get access elasticsearch within my code, and how to confirm that my spark get/post/etc. commands are working.

I have a local elasticsearch server running in the background by command line.

The URL http://localhost:4567/hello I had working last night, but now won't connect or show anything

```
import static spark.Spark.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args)
    {




        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");  //testing readme

        //declare variables to hold local host/port for user?? How do I set that up?
        int port = 9300;
        boolean check = false; //used in  verifying input
        int length = 4; //used in verifying input

        //create scanner object
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Please enter the 4 digit port for the elasticsearch server you will be using.");
            do {

                while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input: please enter a 4 digit number.");
                    sc.next(); // this is important!
                }
                port = sc.nextInt();
                length = String.valueOf(port).length();
                if (length != 4)
                    System.out.println("Invalid input: please enter a 4 digit number.");

            } while ((port <= 0) || (length != 4));
            System.out.println("Success! " + port);




        //on startup
            Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(
                      Settings.builder().put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                                        .put("cluster.name","elasticsearch").build()) 
                      .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), port));

        //testing basic GET requests
            get("/hello", (request, response) -> "Hello World!");

            post("/hello", (request, response) ->
                "Hello World: " + request.body()
            );


        //on shutdown
        sc.close();
        //client.close();
        System.exit(0);


}//end main function

}//end main class
```

I apologize for any lack of specificity. I appreciate any questions, advice, or pushes in the right direction and will respond as best I can to any questions.

EDIT: Also attempting it replacing

```
Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(
                      Settings.builder().put("client.transport.sniff", true)
```

with:

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"));
                Header[] defaultHeaders = new Header[]{new BasicHeader("header", "value")};
                builder.setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders);
```

I don't know if its doing anything, or how to test it, but I'm not getting errors when running it and I suspect its the correct direction since I'm supposed to be making a RESTful API specifically.

Comment: I am assuming that the data will be stored in Elasticsearch and Spark will be used to perform queries on that data. So, first you need to clearly understand the data being stored in ES and the type of operations the REST API needs to support. Your REST API could probably delegate to ES for "find a needle in a haystack" kind of operations. For more complex operations, such as applying machine learning algorithms, you would want to delegate to Spark which would then retrieve data from ES and apply the ML algorithm. Without this information it's hard to make any meaningful recommendations.

Comment: It will be a simple address book, where I create a Contact class with a few attributes, that will be stored and accessed via the API. I only need a few operations, specifically GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE. Does that help at all? As soon as I can begin writing and testing functions using these I’m confident I’ll be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: It's not clear what the role of Spark should be in this implementation because you can implement a simple address book using only Elasticsearch.

Comment: You know, you are totally right. It is listed in the stack I am to use, but never mentioned anywhere else and I did just get elasticsearch to work. Not fully understanding what elasticsearch and spark did, I assumed they had to work together, and went off in the wrong direction. I know it seems simple, but thank you for pointing that out. That really helped. I should be good at this point.